# session microsoft security client oobe stopped

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

i use Windows Server 2008 R2. I connect the server by remote desktop connection. But nowadays the server closes my remote desktop session randomly and all my application running during the session are closed. Simply, my remote desktop connection is forcely logged off by windows. 
When i reconnect, i open event viewer and see that following error:

```
session 'microsoft security client' oobe stopped due to the following error: 0xC000000D
```

What can be reason which makes the server behave like that?

Answer (score 3):

OOBE problem SOLVED ?

IT'S A SECURITY COUNTER

YOU MUST, again, MUST shutdown the security counter.

This is the reason that everyone says to delete the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Security Client\Support\EppOobe.etl file.  This file is used and created by this counter.

DON'T DELETE THE EppOobe.etl file instead

You MUST go into into Computer Management by these steps

-> control panel -> administrative tools -> computer management and drill down into:

System Tools -> Performance -> Data Collector Sets -> Startup Event Tracing Sessions

Then, in the frame to the right on that window, select Microsoft Security Client OOBE, right click on it and select Properties.

Click on the tab Trace Session and

Then DISABLE it (uncheck the Enabled box).  Then, you select OK.

Disabling the MS Security Client Counter as I listed above, will not stop the

Security Esssentials- will run fine without it.
theses steps are for windows 7

Comment: Please do not use caps in your answer!

Comment: This is exactly correct. There are hundreds of posts with random suggestions all over the internet about this problem, and nobody has offered an actual explanation and solution until now.  Great!!

Comment: What is it counting? What am I turning off?